# Javascript RegExp unknown repeated matches

Tags: javascript, regex

It's difficult to describe because I'm not an expert with regular expressions. So I tell you my case.

In HTML want to contribute `class` attributes into different `data-xyz` attributes. The problem is to get always all classes per match. For example the following HTML:

```
<span class="note-123 index-3 green">Hello</span> <span class="index-456 red">World<span>
```

Until now my regular expression is `/<span class="([^\"\s]*)\s*/` and it matches the **first** class. In this case `note-123` and `index-456`

But if I want to get all classes per element I could use `/<span class="([^\"\s]*)\s*([^\"\s]*)\s*([^\"\s]*)\s*/`. That works until **three** classes and the result for the second class return `index-456`, `red` and an empty string.

Is there a possibility to always get all classes per match **no matter how many** classes there are? Similar to a nested loop in Javascript?

I would be pleased to get any help from you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the classes without using a regex making use of [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to find the elements that you want and use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to get the class names.

Then use for example the [add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add) or [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove) methods.

Or use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

**Note** to close the last span.

```js
let elms = document.querySelectorAll("span");
elms.forEach(e => {
  for (let value of e.classList.values()) {
    console.log(value);
  }
});
```

```html
<span class="note-123 index-3 green">Hello</span> <span class="index-456 red">World</span>
```

Comment: Okay that seem to work. Another way I often do is with jQuery but it is unnecessary if I knew all these commands. Think RegExp is a lot faster if I want to prapare a lot of very long documents.

Comment: @MichaelLambertz Why do you want to make it more complicated and error prone? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @MichaelLambertz Why do you think RegEx will be faster?

Comment: It's the fastest way to search in text and manipulate text, isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelLambertz I think that using a regex is slower, but I must say that to be sure you would have to benchmark it. But using a DOMparser has a great benefit, so you might as well take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex to extract the value of the class attribute and split it at whitespace sequences:

```js
let as_classes
  , as_matches
  , n_i
  , re_classes
  , s_test
  ;

  re_classes = new RegExp ( "<span class=\u0022([^\\u0022]*)", "g" );
  s_test = '<span class="note-123 index-3 green">Hello</span> <span class="index-456 red">World<span>';
  n_i=0;
  while ((as_matches = re_classes.exec(s_test)) !== null) {
     n_i++;   
     s_classes = as_matches[1];
     as_classes = s_classes.split(/[\s]+/g);
     
     console.log(`match #${n_i}, classes: ${JSON.stringify(as_classes)}.`);
  }
```

***Warning***

It is <del>in general</del> never a good approach to extract information from html with regexen.

Comment: Thank you. Now it works for the first item. But how can I find the second match classes ["index-456", "red"]. And I want to replace the matches throughout the code.
If it's never a good approach, how would you do it?

Comment: I've updated the answer with code to cater for repeated matches. As for an alternative approach, instead of matching against regexen query the dom (the in-browser representation of html files; check out [the introduction on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)) or parse the html. with a parsing library or using a framework/library that comes with such facilities (like jquery). What is best depends on where the code executes (client/server) and the your task in-the-large.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thanks too for the link and the hint. I often use jquery but I think regexp is much faster than everything else :-/

Comment: When it comes to code writing, factor in the time needed for maintaining your software. Performance-wise, you may interact with the DOM through the DOM API, namely the [`classList` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Of course, this requires that the DOM is available in the first place.